# How to Create Markers Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, google-maps-markers

Can anyone share to me a complete sample project on creating problem markers for the java editor of eclipse.

I'm fairly new to java and I want to create an eclipse plugin that will detect custom coding problems. I've tried doing some research learned that I will need to use markers to accomplish this but I'm having trouble understanding the resources online.

I was hoping that I would understand this better if I have a working sample/project that I can play around with but I cant find one from my searches.

Comment: Samples/templates are built in: in the _File > New > Other...: Plug-in Project_ dialog you have to click _Next_ twice to get to the third page with the checkbox _Creating a plug-in using a template_ (different templates will be displayed depending on what you selected on the second page). There are also [nice tutorials on vogella.com](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/eclipseplatform.html). See also Eclipse wiki, e.g. [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_problem_markers_for_my_compiler%3F) or the source code of Eclipse or of open source plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to read the original [Mark My Words](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html) article on eclipse.org. It's old, but not out of date.